# Pattern attribute value ^[^<>{}[\]!$%*+:=?@^~_\t]+$ is not a valid regular expression

Tags: html, regex, google-chrome, syntax-error

My HTML input tag has this attribute `pattern`(it is a regex expression to validate the coupon code validation)
`pattern=^[^<>{}[\]!$%*+:=?@^~_\t]+$`

At some point in the past few months, Chrome has started returning the following JavaScript error
`Pattern attribute value ^[^<>{}[\]!$%*+:=?@^~_\t]+$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[^<>{}[\]!$%*+:=?@^~_\t]+$/v: Invalid character in character class`

What syntax do I have wrong? or What should I update here??

I've tried to remove the escape character which is used in the regex, but still not expected response

Comment: Right, the `v` flag escaping requirements are stricter than those of the `u` flag. Your pattern can be re-written as ``^[^<>\{\}\[\]!$%*+:=?@^~_\t]+$``